# How to select <source> inside of <video>?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a hard time figuring how could I prop `src` inside of the `<source>` if the `this.$element` is `<video>`?

[image: HTML]

Here's my code:

`this.$element.prop('src', vidsrc === '#' ? inputElement.value : vidsrc );`

Since my code just adding the `src` inside the `<video>`

Take note that the html can't be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the `<source>` elements and their `src` attributes by grabbing the `<video>` element from the DOM and then selecting each `<source>` tag.

To address, changing the `src` attribute of the `<source>` tags based on some condition, below is an example. Using the `updateSrc` function, which accepts three parameters: a position, an array of `<source>` tags, and new `src` value. You can update the `src` for any of the tags that are nested in the `<video>` element.

The function simply checks whether the `<source>` tag exists in the array of elements and if it does, allows for the `src` to be updated and if it doesn't exist then returns false. You can tailor this implementation to your specific needs in terms of conditional checks.

```js
const video = document.getElementById("background");
let sources = video.getElementsByTagName("source");

function updateSrc(pos, arr, src) {
  return arr[pos] ? arr[pos].src = src : false;
}

updateSrc(0, sources, "some-new-src.mp4");
updateSrc(1, sources, "another-new-src.webm");

console.log(sources["0"].src);
console.log(sources["1"].src);
```

```html
<video controls id="background" controlslist="nodownload" width="100%" src="" poster="" style="max-width: 700px;">
    <source src="some-source.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="other-source.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Comment: @Ayaka Does this answer your question? I wasn't sure if you wanted to change the `src` attributes once you targeted them, so this is a starting point.

Comment: Hi!! I tried your code and came up with this `inputElement.value = this.$element[0].getElementsByTagName("source")["0"].src;` and now working (showing the src). But the thing is, how could I possibly change the inside src? Here's my original code `this.$element.prop('src', vidsrc === '#' ? inputElement.value : vidsrc);`

Comment: Hello! Ok that's great you've made some progress. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if it helped solve your initial problem. Addressing changing the `src` based on some condition, I will update my answer with an example of doing that.